# Conditionally scaling specific entries in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to parse a dataframe and scale only values that meet a certain criteria. For instance if I have:

```
df = [1,2,3,4]
```

and I want to scale all values less than 2 by 10, I want to return the following dataframe:

```
df = [10,2,3,4]
```

Right now, my function is as follows:

```
def scaleLessPartColumn(dataFrame, column_name, scale_factor, sort_num):
   dataFrame.ix[(dataFrame[column_name] < sort_num), column_name] *= scale_factor
   return dataFrame
```

But I believe this is scaling the entire column and not specific entries.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you believe this is working? Show us samples of your input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
dataFrame[dataFrame[column_name] < sort_num] *= scale_factor
```

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [5,2,4,3], "C": [2,2,1,4]})

df
#   A   B   C
#0  1   5   2
#1  2   2   2
#2  3   4   1
#3  4   3   4

df[df[["A", "B"]] < 3] *= 10

df
#    A  B   C
#0  10  5   2
#1  20  20  2
#2  3   4   1
#3  4   3   4
```

But you might find this more readable:

```
dataFrame[column_name] = dataFrame[column_name].where(dataFrame[column_name]>=sort_num, 
                                                      dataFrame[column_name]*scale_factor)
```

Comment: Thank you Psidom. I believe my original code also works and I was misunderstanding my results. I really appreciate the more readable code, however. Cheers!